# Is there a way to update the google API key in GoogleService-Info.plist in Flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode, google-api

When the app is scanned for vulnerability test, google api keys are visible .Is there any way to secured so the app pass the PT test.

The app is developed using Flutter.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These keys and identifiers do not represent a security issue. In Firebase you need to set the Rules in order to restrict access to your data as specified by Sam Stern in this reply:

https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/EEEwttbpPJU

> None of the items in the plist file is sensitive, so you don't have to
> worry about someone stealing it.  Make sure that your app has property
> Security Rules on all data (where applicable) and that you enable API
> key restrictions so that nobody can use your API key in their app.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to hide the keys and wasting my time.

Now I change the package google_maps_webservice.
Instead now I am using google_maps_place_picker_mb package and it works like a pro.